Kubuntu 22.04 wlp2s0 wifi connected, but doesn't exist in "connections" app
Running kubuntu 22.04 on older Dell Inspiron P75F.
Wifi connects as wlp2s0 and internet is accessible. However, the device is missing from the "connections" app and the "network" icon on the tray. Therefore, I cannot configure the device.
It would seem to me that at some point I had to set this up to connect to my wifi but that must have been years ago.

Running nmcli c shows nothing except the unused ethernet connection.
I can see the device using iwconfig and this shows the proper ESSID so perhaps this is how it was originally set up?

How can I get this device into Connections so that it works like other connections and allow me to set up a static ip?
Here is a link to the wireless info script as requested.

Please see this question and run the script provided in the answers (the wireless-info script) and then please post a link to a pastebin of the output.

https://pastebin.com/Dr34gSxP

Nobody have any ideas?

So upon further investigation, I found that services were active for both "netplan" and "networkmanager".    I followed instructions in
this article and resolved the issue.

The wireless-info script shows that you have managed=false set in your NetworkManager configuration file:
[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

If you want NetworkManager to manage the network, set managed=true.

First, use the following command or your favorite text editor to open the file:
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Then under the [ifupdown] section, set managed=true:
[ifupdown]
managed=true

Finally, press CTRL+o to save the changes and press CTRL+x to exit nano.
Reboot or restart the NetworkManager systemd service to apply the changes.
Note: keep in mind that you should not use sudo when starting or restarting NetworkManager through systemd. If you accidentally use sudo to start the service, just stop the service using sudo and then start it up without sudo so that your user will have permission to edit your networks using the GUI.

I have made this correction and rebooted, to no avail.
